# error on uploading database to phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm trying to upload a **280MB** database (`.sql`) to **localhost/phpmyadmin** but i keep getting this error:

[image: fatal_error]

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.04\libraries\dbi\mysqli.dbi.lib.php on line 267
```

It's worth mentioning that i changed the `post_max_size` in file `php.ini` to **350M**, and the `upload_max_filesize` (also in file `php.ini`) to **300M**. That's because my `.sql` file is about **300M**.

How can i overcome this?

**edit:**

as @Duikboot suggested, i did the import via cmd, and it worked:

- Go to mysql path. In my case:

  ```
  cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin
  ```
- then connect to your root:

  ```
  mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
  ```
- enter password if you have one

*i'm not sure whether the next 2 steps are necessary if the .sql file has a create database query*

- create a new database:

  ```
  create database NewDataBaseName;
  ```
- use it:

  ```
  use NewDataBaseName;
  ```
- and finally import the file (enter full path). in my case:

  ```
  source c:/testdb.sql;
  ```

  *note that it's a backslash (/) and not a regular slash (\)*

Comment: Try to insert your SQL database with the command line instead of the PHPMyAdmin interface.And there is also an option in your php.ini normally wich is called: "max_execution_time". Try to increase that one.

Answer (score 0):

The error message should give you a clue!!!

```
Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded
```

You will need to increase the allowed execution time as well as the other changes you made.

So edit php.ini ( use the wampmanager menus to make sure you edit the correct file )

Find the parameter `max_execution_time = 300` and increase to `max_execution_time = 900`

**A better solution** is to set all these value specifically for phpmyadmin only. So you dont effect the normal execution of a php script running in the browser. So set the values you changed back to what they were before you changed them, then ...

Edit `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` and add these commands

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/" 

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Require local

    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 300M
    php_admin_value post_max_size 350M
    php_admin_value max_execution_time 600
    php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```